How does Christine's origin differ in the movie rather than the book?
The question I originally posted this to has been deleted, and I was honestly gratified to find proof in the interview, so I'm posting this as a self-answer.
In the 1983 film, Christine, the car is shown to have injured people while on the assembly line, versus the book, where it is introduced through Arnie acquiring the car through LeBey, with some earlier incidents later coming to light of LeBey's daughter and wife having died in the car. How do the origins of the evil of the car differ?

Christine's homicidal nature is never explained in the film. In the book, it's implied that Christine is possessed by Roland LeBay, whose spirit also starts to possess Arnie, but here, there is no explanation provided, and it seems that she attacked people from her first construction.
This Screen Rant article expands on that difference.

At the beginning of John Carpenter's Christine movie, the titular Plymouth Fury is shown to be evil seemingly from its creation, attacking one Chrysler employee and later killing another. Christine's creation is also accompanied by the George Thorogood song "Bad to the Bone," which sort of serves as a theme song for both the movie and Christine itself. This suggests a car that's evil for no real reason other than it just naturally is, although one of the film's taglines, "body by Plymouth, soul by Satan" also hints at an infernal influence. However, in Stephen King's book that's not at all the case.
In the novel, Christine is revealed to be possessed by the car's deceased former owner, a violent man named Roland D. LeBay. Christine's new owner, Arnie Cunningham, begins to take on many of Roland's traits as part of the possession. This could theoretically be argued as true for the film too, if not explicitly mentioned, were it not for Christine claiming victims before she's even been purchased by LeBay. If anything, this suggests that Christine's evil is inherent, and that anyone who owns her will eventually turn to the dark side. In a very bizarre way, the differences in Christine's origin between book and film are almost an example of nature vs. nurture.

King's interview with Lofficier seems to confirm this.

Lofficier: It's difficult to tell from reading the book whether Christine is evil herself, or whether Le Bay makes her evil. From what source do you see the evil emanating?
King: That's one of the questions with which the movie people started to wrestle. Was it Le Bay, or was it the car? I understand that their answer is that it was the car. In fact, it may be -- and I'm just guessing -- that Le Bay isn't anywhere near as sinister as he is in the book. I think that, in the book, there is the suggestion that it's probably Le Bay, rather than the car.
When the film people came to me, I said, "Look, this is your decision. You decide what you're going to do with the story." But, later, I was told that in the opening sequence, when the car rolls off the assembly line, one of the workman is dead behind the wheel. This would give you the idea that the car was bad from the beginning...


As I recall, the first spirit to haunt Christine, in the novel, was LeBay's child, who choked to death inside the car. After LeBay's death, the old man's spirit took control of the vehicle. Christine also seemed to collect the souls of those she killed; during the final battle the protagonist glimpsed numerous figures within the car's cabin.

Huh. I'll double-check my copy later.

@fuzzybootsI located the passage about the child on page 100 of my paperback copy. The protagonist heard the story from LeBay's brother. Also, LeBay's wife committed suicide in the car.
